# Clickhouse: create table as select from another big table with minimal memory usage

Tags: clickhouse

i need to create table from another one.
Main problem that i fear about size of mother table - it is big.

Let's be:

- OLD_BIG_TABLE - my current big table with a lot of data
- NEW_TABLE - my new table in which i need to move data from OLD_BIG_TABLE with transformations
- TRANSFORMATION - my transformation which i will make with data from OLD_BIG_TABLE before save it in NEW_TABLE

Due that i fear that clickhouse will eat all memory and in end falling down, if i will use simple:

```
create table NEW_TABLE
   as select * 
   from {sql with TRANSFORMATION for data from OLD_BIG_TABLE}
```

What the propper way to move from OLD_BIG_TABLE to NEW_TABLE data with minimal memory usage?

---

For example in postgres i can use for that `for loop` statement and move data by chunks (for example day by day).

Comment: in common cases just try to avoid ORDER BY , try to split your query as CREATE ... LIKE + INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE ...